# How do I get to the island point of interest in Kessex Hills?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm trying to find the final point of interest in Kessex Hills. However, it's below the island, and I can't find any cave entrance on the land or in the water nearby.

[image: Where's the dang POI]

How do I get to this POI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That particular Point of Interest gave me some trouble as well. Luckily, one of my guild mates helped me out.

There is a cave on the adjacent island that you must swim into to reach your point of interest. It should be in the general vicinity of the heart on that same island, as illustrated by this freehand circle.

[image]

Additionally, this YouTube video, courtesy of sjohnston illustrates it very well:

Comment: I also found this video, which does a nice job of showing where the cave entrance is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcLXX9ZcGzk